# Double thresholding is automatic, semi-automatic or manual segmentation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have used two threshold values for segmenting an image, Is it automatic, semi-automatic or manual segmentation.

```
I = imread('tumor1.jpg');
I(I<=140) = 0;
I(I>=225) = 0;
BW = im2bw(I,graythresh(I));
imshow(BW)
```

Comment: So what exactly are you asking?  BTW, your question is related to MATLAB.  If you want more exposure or people to help you more quickly, please include which programming languages you're using in the tags.

Comment: I have already mentioned my programming language MATLAB.

Comment: No you haven't.  It isn't anywhere in your post.  I **had to add that in for you**.  Going back to my original question... what exactly are you trying to ask?  What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use first a two-level **manual** segmentation by saying that all pixel intensities that are not between 140 and 225 are background pixels. Later, you use Otsu thresholding, which is an **automatic** segmentation tool. If you are going to use this code just for once, or if you need to change the manual segmentation parameters each time, I'd call your approach a **semi-automatic** approach.

However, if you can use this code for **all** your images, you have clearly written an automatic segmentation script, which required initially some effort to set the manual threshold values right.